# How to customize tag and category post listings to show introductory content?

Tags: categories, tags, content

In wordpress, we allow google to index our category and tag pages. We don't use no-index for tag or categories, which results very high ranking in a lots of keywords and we are receiving very high traffic from google. We also use Wordpress SEO for SEO.

We don't have so many control on the content of category or tag because the content is creating by underlying posts.

So, I need to find a plug-in to create specific content in tag or category like following

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hi3PZSDfRfQ 
http://www.tizish.com/how-to-add-html-in-your-wordpress-category-introductory-content/

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin for that. You have at *least* two options:

1. Take advantage of the Category/Tag *description* field, to create content to output either on a `category.php`/`tag.php` template file, or else in `archive.php` or `index.php` inside an `if ( is_category() )`/`if ( is_tag() )` conditional.
2. If you really need to customize your "introductory" content, create `category-foo-bar.php` template files, where`foo-bar` corresponds to the category slug (i.e. for category *Foo Bar*), and put in whatever content you need/want. Wash, rinse, and repeat for each category.

**EDIT**

One other solution: add a Dynamic Sidebar (i.e. Widget area) to the top of your Category archive index, and then use Text Widgets (with conditional logic, e.g. via the Widget Logic Plugin) to add whatever "introductory content" you want to add.

Comment: Actually, We need title and description and show these text boxes in category or tag admin page like we see title , description boxes for wordpress SEO. 

And we also need standard html editor that wordpress using for post to write the description. 

There should be a simple plugin for this.

Comment: We have more than 400 editors in your network. introductory Category/tag description/title should be writing from the admin panel.... and we have more than 100 categories and 5000 tags... :)))

Comment: What Title do you need, other than the Category Name? Also, the Category Description field accepts HTML.

Comment: our category pages has high ranks in google. We have more than 100 categories ranked 1-2 or 3 rd page in google.  We need to increase it. One way to increase the category page to add special introductory content.

Comment: You just answered *why* you want to add "introductory content"; but that doesn't explain *what* content you want to add. In any case, see edited answer for another alternative for how to add this content.

Comment: Chip, you are right about the my answer. Our editor will decided the content. It might be a few small paragraphs with some h3 and p explaining the category or tag .... like in about.com category pages.